# PHP question mark on Clean URLs

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

i am currently trying to learn about clean urls. i was using windows once.
i switched to ubuntu when suddenly my .htaccess seems to be not working
here is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

so i have this url

> http://localhost/index.php/my_name/

i was expecting it to say the 'my_name' string in the browser

**hello my_name**

but it would only work whenever i add a '?' in the uri

> http://localhost/index.php?/my_name/

i am pretty sure mod_rewrite is enabled. i even checked my phpinfo()

Comment: Maybe u have no mod_rewrite module installed? Check httpd.conf and check your logs ([info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog))

Comment: What is the code in your index.php file?

Comment: this time i have my mod_rewrite enabled but it still needs a ? in order to echo out the $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]

Comment: @john echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the rewrite module is disabled. Edit your apache configuration and load the dynamic module for `mod_rewrite` if available. It would look like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

If you're using Ubuntu, run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable the module following by restarting the Apache server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: so i would put the LoadModule inside the httpd.conf? damn its hard being a windows user xD

Comment: @kapitanluffy What Linux distro are you using? Generally, you've indeed to put that in httpd.conf, but distros may have their own preferred configuration methods.

Comment: @kapitanluffy I've already mentioned how to enable the rewrite module for Ubuntu using `a2enmod` ("Apache 2.x ENable MODule"). Don't forget to restart the server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: i already enabled it .but it still needs a ? in order to echo the $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING] variable

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. dumped the $_SERVER variable and used the REQUEST_URI index since QUERY_STRING does not display anything. will +1 Lekensteyn's answer since it led me to the right path